# Change the android options menu layout

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I'm using android options menu defined in xml under the \menu folder.
The menu have 5 items in it, and they are shown in the layout on two lines - the top line contains 2 items and the bottom line contains the other 3 items.

Is there a way to configure the menu so the top line will contain 3 items and the bottom line will contain the other 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you put menu items in one group it will try to keep them together. To control order of menu items is better when you create Menu in your activity, not using XML. In your activity you can get menu items in group something like this:

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
        int group1Id = 1; 

        int Id1 = Menu.FIRST;
        int Id2 = Menu.FIRST +1;
        int Id3 = Menu.FIRST +2;

             super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

                menu.add(group1Id, Id1, 1, "Option 1");
                menu.add(group1Id, Id2,  2, "Option 2");
                menu.add(group1Id, Id3,  3, "Option 3");
                      return true;
            }      

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:        //for option 1


                return true;
            case 2:      //for option 2

                return true;
            case 3:        //for option 3


                return true;      
                   default:
                return false;
            }
```

**Parameters**:
**groupId**  The group identifier that this item should be part of.

**itemId**  Unique item ID. Use NONE if you do not need a unique ID.

**order**  The order for the item. Use NONE if you do not care about the order.

**title**  The text to display for the item.

**Returns**:
The newly added menu item.

Comment: I've tried to define a group on the menu xml and the items display did not changed.
I'm wondering if creating it on code would change it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use different layouts for the options menu
for example :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menuRefresh"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
     android:title="Refresh"
      android:showAsAction = "always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
     android:title="About"
     android:showAsAction = "always"/>
</menu>
```

You can use "never" "withtext" "ifRoom" "always" "collapseActionView" 
[or you can read out full details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)